# Show one content on every desktop page, except on home. Show other content on mobile

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I try to achieve the following on my Wordpress site:

Show content A on every Desktop page, except Home.
Show content B on every Mobile page, except Home.
Show content C on Home (regardless if it's Desktop or Mobile). FYI, Home has page ID 10.

This is my code:

```
<?php 
add_action( 'astra_content_before' , 'text_insert', 5 );
function text_insert() {

global $post;
 if((! $post->ID == 10) OR (!is_wp_mobile)){

echo "This will show up on all desktop pages but never homepage";
    }
    elseif((! $post->ID == 10) AND (is_wp_mobile)){
    echo "This will show up on all mobile pages but not on homepage";
}
    else {
    echo "this will show up on home";
    }
    }
    
    ?>
```

But all it does, is showing "this will show up on home" on ALL pages. What am I missing?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked whether `$post` even contains anything at this point? Maybe you should rather use a function like `is_front_page` to determine this.

Comment: @CBroe Unfortunately, replacing `$post->ID==10` with `is_front_page` does not change anything.

Comment: `is_wp_mobile` is a function, but you are not actually calling it. But even if you do, combining those two conditions with OR makes little sense - when you are on dekstop, then `!is_wp_mobile()` _will_ be true, making the whole condition true, regardless of whether you are on the front page or not.

Comment: is_wp_mobile in your code is wrong should be is_wp_mobile() - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_mobile/#comment-547

Comment: @CBroe, ok thanks. So can you help me how I should express the function as "If not Home and not Mobile"?

Comment: Well logical _and_ instead of _or_ ...